# How can I find out the credit rating of a company

Tags: investing, credit-score

I have shares in RIOCAN (REI.UN.TO) and I am wondering if it is possible to lookup the credit rating of this company? I only found this one but it seems like an old one, I cannot tell the date:
http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/sp-harmonizes-riocan-reit-ratings-at-bbb-outlook-stable-71567147.html

What is the quick way to find an updated credit rating of RIOCAN?

Answer (score 1):

You can view Standard & Poor's credit ratings here:  http://www.standardandpoors.com/ratings/en/us/

You have to register with S&P to access the ratings.

Answer (score 1):

[Dunn & Bradstreet](https://creditreports.dnb.com/m/home) offers detailed credit reports on businesses.  They are not cheap, but they appear to have [information on RIOCAN](https://creditreports.dnb.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/IballValidationCmd?storeId=11154&catalogId=71154&searchType=BSF&busName=riocan&state=ON&country=CA&productId=0&cm_mmc=cr-_-home-_-retail-_-lookup-_-herospot#goTop).